# Can't compile subroutine with array output with f2py

Tags: fortran, f2py

I have a subroutine that I'm writing in Fortran to be compiled with f2py and the compilation is failing. I won't post the full subroutine here but a MWE is:

```
SUBROUTINE mwe(Vars, nxc, nyc, vCorr)
IMPLICIT NONE
real(kind=8), dimension(:,:,:,:) :: Vars
integer :: nxc, nyc
integer :: dims(4), nv, nt, nx, ny
real(kind=8), intent(out), allocatable :: vCorr(:,:,:,:)

dims = shape(Vars)
nv=dims(1)
nt=dims(2)
nx=dims(3)
ny=dims(4)
allocate(vCorr(nv, nt, 2*nxc+1, 2*nyc+1))

print*,size(vCorr)
print*,size(Vars)
END SUBROUTINE
```

This fails with

```
/tmp/tmpy43di1/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/mwe-f2pywrappers.f:30:31:

       call mwe(vars, nxc, nyc, vcorr)
                               1
Error: Actual argument for ‘vcorr’ must be ALLOCATABLE at (1)
```

Which apparently means that f2py doesn't accept allocatable output arrays. So I tried to circumvent this problem by passing the shape `Vars` as an array, so `vCorr` doesn't have to be allocated, which led me to this code

```
SUBROUTINE mwe(Vars, nxc, nyc, dims, vCorr)
IMPLICIT NONE
real(kind=8), dimension(:,:,:,:) :: Vars
integer :: nxc, nyc
integer :: dims(4)
real(kind=8) :: vCorr(dims(1),dims(2),2*nxc+1,2*nyc+1)

print*,size(vCorr)
print*,size(Vars)
END SUBROUTINE
```

Which fails with this error

```
/tmp/tmp0Y1S9x/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/mwemodule.c:296:39: error: called object ‘dims’ is not a function or function pointer
   vcorr_Dims[0]=dims(1),vcorr_Dims[1]=dims(2),vcorr_Dims[2]=2 * nxc + 1,vcorr_Dims[3]=2 * nyc + 1;
```

After some look around I came across [this page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5029) which leads me to believe (even though I'm using f2py2, and not 3) that this is a bug.

Any suggestions around this?

Comment: The suggestion is not to use allocatable array arguments. F2py does not support them. Probably there is a duplicate around. The other looks like a bug.

Comment: @VladimirF Yeah, but if the option that uses allocatable arrays isn't supported, and the other one gives me a bug, what are the other options?

Comment: Dont use dims array, but single scalar variables dim1 and dim2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example f2py does not support allocatable array arguments. They do not fit well with Python arrays.

In the other example f2py does not understand `dims(1),dims(2)` in `vCorr(dims(1),dims(2)`. It does not support array elements there. This is a bug.

As a workaround use scalar variables for the dimensions

```
SUBROUTINE mwe(Vars, nxc, nyc, dim1, dim2, vCorr)
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  real(dp), dimension(:,:,:,:) :: Vars
  integer :: nxc, nyc
  integer :: dim1, dim2
  real(dp) :: vCorr(dim1,dim2,2*nxc+1,2*nyc+1)
```

---

Note: `kind=8` is ugly and not portable. The true meaning is NOT 8 bytes, although it does correspond to 8 byte reals in many compilers. But not in all of them. Even the good old `double precision` is better.

Comment: I understand this, but I was trying to avoid that because my plan is to extend this routine to arrays of more dimensions (probably 6 or more). So it kind of becomes a problem passing that many individual integers in the correct order. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I don't think so. You might try derived type, I expect the same problem.